# cakephp auth session regeneration

Tags: cakephp

> 1. We are using Cakephp framework version 2.0.6
> 2. The site is "supposed" to allow an anonymous user to "add to cart."
> 3. We are using the session id (using cake's native session class) to store the anonymous user's information in a db table.
> 4. When the user goes to checkout, then we want to ask "**are you a current member? If so, click yes to login or no to create an account.**"

**ISSUE:**

Regardless of what they choose, the user either then has to login, or create a new user/pass (and then login) which is causing cakephp to regenerate a session ID.  This is making it impossible in the new session to grab what that user added to the cart when they were anonymous just 5 minutes prior.  In other words, the anonymous user's session id changes between when they are anonymous and after they login/create-user, making it impossible to identify their cart post-login.

Is there a way to prevent cakephp from regenerating a session in this scenario, or a better way to accomplish what we are trying to do while still keeping our order flow *(ie: anonymous being allow to add to cart, before login/create)*?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690140/preserve-session-id-after-login-cakephp) may be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this reason that shopping carts are more often than not stored in Cookies. That way you can easily retrieve the saved information post-authentication.

If you insist on using Sessions to store this data, consider setting your Security.level setting to 'low'. That should prevent CakePHP from regenerating the session ID.

Comment: Setting it to medium should have the same effect on further inspection

Comment: changed the secuirty to low as well used db based session.. It still keeps changing.

Comment: Have you managed to find any better way to resolve this? Without setting security level to low.

Comment: It does not look a better way to do this.