# Preserve session id after login CakePHP

Tags: php, session, cakephp

There are some similar questions in Stack Overflow but no one give me a clue how to deal with my issue.

I'm migrating my app from CakePHP 1.3 to 2.x and I have issue with cart. My users able to add items to cart while not logged and I merge their cart's items after login. In 1.3 it works well because session id wasn't changed after login, but now that feature is broken because session id is changed after user login.

Is there any way to leave old session id after login or I need to write something on my own? If so, what  can be "best practice" here?

Currently I save into DB carts for authentificated users with their `user_id` and for anonymous users with their `session_id` and after login I just find cart by `user_id` and `session_id`, merge items and than delete cart with `session_id` but now it's impossible to do because of `session_id` change.

Comment: You can just keep cart info for unauthenticated users in session and you won't lose it after login.

Comment: Thanks, it was surprise for me. I have not checked that case because of changing `session_id` so i believe that session data was lost either. But now i just save anonymous `session_id` into `Session` in AppController and every time check if it was set and user is authentificated i'm doing merge cart's items with that `session_id` instead of current. While accepted answer is correct i can't use that approach because there are more than one login methods in my app.

Comment: Auth component regenerates session id after login for security reasons. The session data is retained when PHP regenerates new session id. The only reason you are having issues is you use the stale session id. I don't see much benefit in saving cart of unauthenticated users in database. Keep it in session and then persist to db after they login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in source of [AuthComponent](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-AuthComponent.html#550) you can see it is the default behavior in cake 2.x, in order to prevent session fixation. 
I think the easiest solution would be to read your session data before you're calling the login action and on success write or merge the data back into new session. If you need to keep the old session id, add it into session after login as well.

```
if ($this->Session->check('Cart.session_id')) {
    $sessionId = $this->Session->read('Cart.session_id');
} else {
    $sessionId = session_id();
}
$userId = $this->Session->read('Cart.user_id');
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    // on successful login find your customer in DB and merge the session data like you did
    ...
    // in the case you need to keep the session_id for reference...
    $this->Session->write('Cart.session_id') = $sessionId;
}
```

Hope it helps...

**update** - if you cannot use it like I showed, even simpler option is to store the `session_id()` inside the session, at the same time when you insert or update user's order details. So just this snippet:

```
if (!$this->Session->check('Cart.session_id')) {
    $this->Session->write('Cart.session_id', session_id());
}
```

This info will live as long as the session, or until you unset it.

Comment: This is little bit overdone. I believe that it's possible to leave only `$sessionId = session_id();` and after `if ($this->Auth->login())` use it instead of real session id to merge my cart items. So using `Session` here is useless. But i will accept your answer because it's correct and i have done something like that. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about the whole use case, so I added more than is needed. However, why not store the session_id, in the session if it's not set yet? By doing that, session regeneration is not an issue, you don't need any extra logic in AppController, and you will just do `$this->Session->read('your_session_id')` where you need it...

Answer (score -1):

when yoy log in you create a session, so to read data from the session you can read it like this :

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.user_id);
```

User is the model name.

Comment: I need to get `session_id` of the session was *before* user login. Or way to preserve same `session_id` after user logins.

Comment: If we think about that comment in case of preserving session data after login while `session_id` is changed so that answer not such incorrect as it was before.